# Excel VBA Internet explorer - information from 2 columns within a table

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, html-parsing, vba

I am trying to get information from a webpage.
The information i need is in a table and I am failing to address it directly.
this is the page:
http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=matratze

the table id is: plist
each row i need has the name "js4offer"
and than i need the 2nd and the 3rd "tr" from within the table-row but i have no idea how i can loop trough all the elements within this one table.
i tried out thousands of code snippet but none of them is doing what i wanna do ;)

here´s my code so far:

```
Sub website()

    Set sht = Sheets("Tabelle4")
    rCount = 1

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=Matratze"

        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set objHTML = objIE.Document
        readText = objHTML.body.outerHTML
        Cells(1, 1) = readText

        Set myElements = objHTML.getElementById("plist")

        For Each ele In myElements

            If ele.getElementsByName("js4offer") Then
                rCount = rCount + 1
                Cells("A", rCount) = ele.Item(1)
                Cells("B", rCount) = ele.Item(2)
            End If

        Next ele

    End With

    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what other problems you would encounter, but running your script will give loss of content as a cell can only contain 32,767 characters, which is less than the webpage contains. So you lose data by pasting in a single cell...

Comment: i just want the "name" of the product and the price. (tr 1 and tr3 within "js4offer")
i was just putting the readText in a cell to see if the html is loaded correctly

Comment: You could use Data > From Web as an alternative method and then use the excel worksheet to get the information you require. The different elements will be presented in different columns, you can even only have the part with the products shown in the worksheet. You can change the url of this link via VBA and thus loop through different items if you want that.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

FYI : In Table plist except for the first all the tr have name "js4offer".

```
Sub website()


' Set sht = Sheets("Tabelle4")
'  rCount = 1

    Dim objIE As Object, objTbl As Object, objTR As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=Matratze"

        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set objTbl = objIE.Document.getElementById("plist")
        Set objTR = objTbl.getElementsbyTagName("tr")


        rCount = 1
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each td In objTR
            Cells(rCount, 1) = td.all(0).innerText
            Cells(rCount, 2) = td.all(1).innerText
            Cells(rCount, 3) = td.all(2).innerText
           ' Cells(rCount, 4) = td.all(3).innerText
            'Cells(rCount, 5) = td.all(4).innerText
            'Cells(rCount, 6) = td.all(5).innerText
            'Cells(rCount, 7) = td.all(6).innerText
            rCount = rCount + 1
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```